# IntelliSense: an array may not have elements of this type

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a 2D array and then I will search for the right rate when I find the income I need.

To test my array and make sure everything works I need it to print. Problem is it keeps saying array may not have elements of this type...

An array may not have elements of this type. Why is it not allowing me to enter all of these rates in the subscript.

```
int main(void)
{ 
    float income[] = {6000.00, 9000.00, 15000.00, 21000.00, 25000.00, 30000.00};
    float rates[][] = { { 2.8, 7.5, 9.6, 13.5, 15.5, 17.4 }, { 2.8, 7.5, 9.6, 13.5, 15.5, 17.4 } };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf(" \n %i# income array:  %.2f \n", i, income[i]);

        printf("\n  %f ", rates[1][i]);
    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: That is almost certainly *not* the error message you are getting.  Paraphrasing is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2 dimensional arrays, you must provide the inner dimension:

```
float rates[][6] = { { 2.8, 7.5, 9.6, 13.5, 15.5, 17.4 }, { 2.8, 7.5, 9.6, 13.5, 15.5, 17.4 } };
```